# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (700,227,3) into shape (0,227,3)

Tags: opencv, numpy

Please help me to rectify the errors. This is an Opencv feature extraction code.

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import cv2


ESC=27   
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
orb = cv2.ORB()
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)

imgTrainColor=cv2.imread('train.jpg')
imgTrainGray = cv2.cvtColor(imgTrainColor, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

kpTrain = orb.detect(imgTrainGray,None)
kpTrain, desTrain = orb.compute(imgTrainGray, kpTrain)

firsttime=True

while True:

ret, imgCamColor = camera.read()
imgCamGray = cv2.cvtColor(imgCamColor, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
kpCam = orb.detect(imgCamGray,None)
kpCam, desCam = orb.compute(imgCamGray, kpCam)
matches = bf.match(desCam,desTrain)
dist = [m.distance for m in matches]
thres_dist = (sum(dist) / len(dist)) * 0.5
matches = [m for m in matches if m.distance < thres_dist]   

if firsttime==True:
    h1, w1 = imgCamColor.shape[:2]
    h2, w2 = imgTrainColor.shape[:2]
    nWidth = w1+w2
    nHeight = max(h1, h2)
    hdif = (h1-h2)/2
    firsttime=False

result = np.zeros((nHeight, nWidth, 3), np.uint8)
result[hdif:hdif+h2, :w2] = imgTrainColor
result[:h1, w2:w1+w2] = imgCamColor

for i in range(len(matches)):
    pt_a=(int(kpTrain[matches[i].trainIdx].pt[0]), int(kpTrain[matches[i].trainIdx].pt[1]+hdif))
    pt_b=(int(kpCam[matches[i].queryIdx].pt[0]+w2), int(kpCam[matches[i].queryIdx].pt[1]))

cv2.line(result, pt_a, pt_b, (255, 0, 0))

cv2.imshow('Camara', result)

key = cv2.waitKey(30)                                 
if key == ESC:
    break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
camera.release()
```

ERRORS APPEARING:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sift.py", line 39, in 
result[hdif:hdif+h2, :w2] = imgTrainColor
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (700,227,3) into      shape (0,227,3)

Answer (score 0):

Without digging through your code in detail

```
 result[hdif:hdif+h2, :w2] = imgTrainColor

 ... from shape (700,227,3) into shape (0,227,3)
```

I duduce that `imgTrainColor` is 3d with shape (700,227,3).

`result` must has (3,) last dimension; the `:w2` must be slicing 227 vales.  But the `hdif:hdif+h2` is slicing 0, probably because `h2` is 0.

In other words, you are trying to put the `imgTrainColor` values into a block of `result` that is too small.

Can I leave to you to figure out why `h2` is wrong?  Another possibility is the `hdif` is too large (>700).  You may need to print those indexing values just before this error.

Oh, and clean up the indentation.